# What does “going concern” mean?

Tags: accounting, audit

A local politician is spreading demeaning comments about a company that has its accounts done using a “going concern” basis.

My understanding is that this just means that it is assumed that the company can continue to be solvent for the foreseeable future. [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/goingconcern.asp) seems to back this up.

However, the politician keeps insisting that a company whose accounts are done with this assumption is in trouble, according to the SEC. I’ve tried googling, but my google-fu fails me.

Can anyone clarify why a “going concern” basis might be a bad thing?

Comment: Not easy to say without much more context. Perhaps the politician is claiming that the company has _actually_ made a decision to to close down operations at some point in the near future, but still continues to value its capital assets by going-concern principles such that its financial reports look more optimistic than they ought to?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The company just listed on the NYSE. It is in no such danger.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a quote of the exact wording? You can leave out the name of the politician and the wider textual context etc (no intent to defame).

Comment: I think the suggestion is that even using that term means there is a question as to whether the company is on solid footing or not. Meaning that if the company was sound, that wording would not be included in the reporting at all.

Comment: @4dcndn My reading of the Investopedia definition linked to in the question is that if a company is *not* a going concern, then it's bankrupt... which I would have thought a worse connotation than a company that can continue to exist?

Comment: @PeterK. The period of time in which a company is approaching bankruptcy is of critical interest to anyone involved with the company. Declaration of bankruptcy can nullify debts, agreements, employment contracts, etc.. Many parties may change their relationship to a company if they suspect that company might even be considering bankruptcy.

Answer (score 2):

**This is one of those terms that is used just slightly differently by accounting professionals than how it appears to the general public**. The short version is - having your accounting performed on a 'going concern' basis means it is expected that the operations of the underlying business will continue. ie: its assets are not about to be sold and the company is not about to go bankrupt.

Hard to know exactly what was meant in this specific case without seeing the exact wording, but the general principal goes like this:

"Concern" in this case is a noun, meaning [wording per dictionary.com] "something that relates or pertains to a person; business; affair: - ie: Law is the concern of lawyers."

A "going concern" is basically the notion that some type of business arrangement exists **and is ongoing**.

If you own a van and sell it on kijiji, you're just selling a van. The value of your van would just be the price anticipated to sell it for - let's say $30k. If you run a moving business that owns a single van, and you earn say $1k net profit every week, the value of your business could be more than just $30k. Even if you own no other assets, the valuation of your business should consider that instead of selling the van for $30k, you could continue operating and earning money.

When auditing a business, if it is near-bankruptcy, some elements of reporting financial statements may change. For example, if you own a fleet of vehicles that are about to be sold, their value should be limited to just what you could get when selling them, which would sometimes require that you 'write down' their value, basically as an additional loss reported that year.

**The 'going concern' test referred to in audit is basically the notion to consider whether that business is actually a going concern or not, because if the future of the business is in doubt, then it could change reporting.** Since most businesses *are* 'going concerns' that intend to continue operating, this concept often isn't mentioned unless it is in doubt. So someone might refer to a 'going concern' test being done during an audit, which is basically confirmation that the business is expected to continue operations.

Because of the alternate meaning of the word 'concern' [ie: worry], you might hear the term 'going concern' backwards, and infer that someone is "concerned" that the business is about to close. The exact usage of the phrase here will matter.